# Can we say that the sum of infinite numbers in a sequence is equal to a finite number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is more of a semantic question. I was thinking of the phrase *"An infinite sum of numbers equals a finite number"*

For example, in the limit to infinity, the series $ S_n = \frac{1}{2^n} $ is 2.

Can we say that the infinite sum of the terms of the sequence $ \{ \frac{1}{2^n} \} $ is **equal** to a finite number? Or strictly speaking, is only the limit to infinity of that series that equals 2 and an infinite sum only gets closer and closer to the value 2.

Comment: We say this sort of thing routinely, as when we declare that $.11111\cdots $  "equals" $\frac 19$.

Comment: The sum of an infinite series is defined to be the limit of the partial sums, if it exists. But the sum ***equals*** the limit, the sum does not get closer and closer to anything because the sum is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize this example: “we say”

$\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{k\geq 0} x^k $

for $|x|<1$.